# Namespaced shortcode?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, shortcode, performance

I'm in the middle of revamping a legacy WP-site which has a lot of custom shortcodes and apparently due to how the code is currently organized, these shortcodes are taking a toll in terms of performance.

Sure, I can fix the poorly optimized code and live with the dozen shortcodes and call it a day, but I'm wondering how can I organize them better.

According to WordPress' [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes/basic-shortcodes/#in-a-plugin), it's recommended to place them in a plugin and initialize them on `init`. Can we reduce the load in this hook by "namespacing" them, like this?

```
[com.company shortcode attr="attr" prop="prop"]
```

Has anyone experimented with such solutions? Any drawbacks (except the overhead because of the namespace)?

Comment: How would namespacing reduce load?

Comment: @JacobPeattie According to Xdebug Trace logs, initializing this many shortcodes hurting the site's performance. My idea is to initialize only one shortcode (`com.company`) and move all functionality to its attributes. Does this answer your question? Should I clarify my OP?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, this is not how shortcodes work. Your solution will not reduce performance problems.

At initialization the only thing WordPress does is make a list of all shortcodes that are being registered. If you look at the [order in which WordPress is loading stuff](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) you will see that plugins are loaded before the theme and init hooks. This means that if you try to do things in a plugin which WP is no expecting at that time, nothing will happen.

One of those things is adding shortcodes. So, in a plugin you must postpone adding the shortcode until the init hook. That is what the example you are referring to means. It has nothing to do with performance. Just registering a shortcode causes no load on the server.

WP only starts doing stuff with a shortcode once it encounters one in a post. That's when inefficiently written code will be taking its toll. The only way to reduce that is rewriting it (or removing it). You can use a plugin like [T&P profiler](https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-plugin-profiler/) to pin down which functions are eating most server time (disclosure: I wrote that plugin and yes, it still works, even if it hasn't been updated for some time).